# How to set the unbuffered result set size on PHP PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I got the difference between the buffered and unbuffered query in PDO [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php)

I am working on a query that returns 2M records affecting the PHP memory limit, so I chose the unbuffered query but needed to know How many records transferred on each fetch? and Is there any way to set the record size for each fetch to reduce the number of times data transfer in the same connection?

Answer (score 1):

Whether you are using the buffered or unbuffered mode, MySQL will send the results row by row. There's no way to read the rows in batches.

The only difference between these two modes is whether the result data is stored on the MySQL server or in the PHP runtime memory.

In theory, the buffered mode is better and should be faster, but in practice, the difference is barely noticeable. There are also very few reasons to use unbuffered mode. If your application reads 2M rows, then it's a sign that your application logic might need some redesign. If your application reads the row, does something with the data, and discards the row immediately, then unbuffered results might help you reduce memory usage in PHP, but the database server will still buffer that data in its memory.